# How to make collapsible comment box (part II)

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-app-engine

I wish to follow up with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456163/how-to-make-collapsible-comment-box-like-stackoverflow) asked earlier. Right now, i would like to do the same thing. However, i wish to use ajax to load the comment box itself & not refresh the entire page itself. I am using google app engine platform with python as the main language. How can i modify those codes given by the question to fit mine & integrate the usage of ajax. Here's an idea how i am populating:

```
            {% extends "_base.htm" %}
            {% block bodycontent %}
            <h1>App Engine Chat</h1>
            <p>
            <form method="post" action="/chat">
            <input type="text" name="message" size="60"/>
            <input type="submit" name="Chat"/>      
            </form>
            </p>
            {% ifnotequal error None %}
            <p>
            {{ error }}
            </p>
             {% endifnotequal %}
            <div id="chatcontent">
               Loading...
            </div>

           <script>
               function updateMsg() { 
               $.ajax({
               url: "/messages",
               cache: false,
               success: function(html){
               $("#chatcontent").html(html);
               }
               });
               setTimeout('updateMsg()', 4000);
               }
               updateMsg();
              </script>
             {% endblock %}
```

I also need to display only the 10 newest comments and hide the rest of the message chain. Thanks in advance...

Comment: What about planning for Part 3 ?

Comment: @Sarfraz i believe it is on its way

Answer (score 2):

Use JQuery's toggle function for collapsing and expanding. Make a serverside function for returning only the last ten comments. This way you can fill your page with the comments immediatly at the request. Make sure the div is collapsed by default.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. But i would like to keep it such that after it collapsed, it does not need to repack itself.

Comment: When you just make you page without any javascript and showing the 10 comments you fulfilled one of your needs. After that just use jquery to toggle the div with you comments. The you haven't any repacking. $('.target').toggle();
Set this code on for example you <h3>Comments</h3> this can also be done by jquery